# Перенос строки из одного DataTable в другой(Решено)

Tags: c#, datatable

Нужно перенести определённые строки из одной переменной DataTable в другую. При попытке сделать это, образом, показанным ниже, возникает исключение. Как можно исправить это исключение?

```
dr = dt.Rows[i];
dr.Delete();
dt.AcceptChanges();
dt_temp.Rows.Add(dr);
```

В dt у меня находятся данные - результат запроса к БД. В программе реализован алгоритм, который отбирает строки, удовлетворяющие определённым критериям. По моей задумке, данные удовлетворяющие строки должны накапливаться в dt_temp, а затем выводится в Grid посредством:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = dt_temp
```

Именно для этого мне и нужно переносить данные из одной переменной в другую.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил проблему. Всё заключалось в том, что я просто объявлял dt_temp и не создавал в нём столбцы. После того, как я создал столбцы, аналогичные dt, всё заработало.

Comment: получить строку из таблицы1, вытащить из неё данные, создать строку в таблице2, засунуть туда вытащенные данные.

Comment: Чет как-то сложно, не понимаю зачем вы переносите работу сервера БД в ваше приложение. Вполне стандартная задача - предфильтрация + фильтрация, прекрасно решается в рамках одного запроса. Или у вас какая-то дивная БД, которая это не позволяет?

Comment: @rdorn позволяет, дело в том, что с SQL я слабо знаком и только сейчас изучаю его

Comment: Ну тогда стоило задать вопрос про работу с БД. В любом случае для ответа нужно понимать структуру таблиц с которыми вы работаете (не важно, DataTable или таблицы БД) и какой результат ожидаете. Вариантов решения больше одного, какой нужен вам я пока не знаю.

Comment: Хорошо, что разобрались :) Писать «решено» в заголовке, пожалуй, не стоит. Лучше [опубликуйте ответ на свой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) и отметьте его как решение.

Comment: Не понимаю что есть в коде dr ? Как создать dr ? Помогите пожалуйста !!!